# Резервное копирование баз данных в PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, резервное-копирование

Начал разбираться с резервным копированием баз данных в Postgre. Копии будут делаться для 1С предприятия.
Начитал две утилиты для резервного копирования:

```
pg_dump
```

Как я понял служит для копии одной БД.

```
pg_dumpall
```

Для копии всего кластера баз данных. 
Если верно понял то с `pg_dumpall`мы создадим бэкап всех имеющихся БД. И использовать его наверное лучше тогда, когда мы все перносим на другой сервер.

Вот сам вопрос, а можно ли из бэкапа сделанного с помощью `pg_dumpall` востановить только интересующие нас базы данных. 
К примеру: есть 5 баз, хочу востановить 1 или 2. Возможно вообще такое?

Или лучше использовать `pg_dump` для каждой базы?

Comment: [попробуем-ка поискать в google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=pg_dumpall+restore+one+database&oq=pg_dumpall+restore+one&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.9590j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pg_dumpall` сгенерирует текстовый файл с sql-командами. Поэтому в принципе из него достать дамп отдельной базы можно. Только неудобно, надо каким-то сторонним способом найти границы результата `pg_dump`. `pg_dump` же в свою очередь не способен сохраняться глобальные данные кластера СУБД - например, список баз данных или пользователей.

Поэтому обычно используются оба. `pg_dumpall -g` для сохранения глобальных данных, и `pg_dump` для сохранения слепков интересующих баз данных.

---

Отдельный вопрос, является ли дамп вообще бекапом. Надо понимать, что дамп - это слепок базы на момент начала дампа, восстанавливаться можно только на этот самый момент и может быть довольно длительно по времени.

В качестве именно бекапа рассматривается `pg_basebackup` копия всего кластера и архив WAL сегментов с момента начала `pg_basebackup` до желаемого момента восстановления

Comment: Если я все верно понял, то из sql файла созданного `pg_dumpall ` можно удалить строки которые учавствуют в создании не интересующих нас баз данных. Ну и собственно простого способа достать нужные нам базы нет. Для моих целей наверное будет достаточно использовать `pg_dump` для необходимых мне баз. Т.к. их всего 3 шт.

Comment: верно, простого способа отделить нет. Потому обычно и делают отдельно pg_dump для нужных баз.

Answer (score 0):

> Дамп это не бэкап.

Я тут ещё открою еще один способ сделать копию. У меня в кронтабе на юзере постгрес:

```
  0 6  *   *   *        pg_basebackup -x --write-recovery-conf --format=t -z --pgdata=$BACKPATH$($DATE)/pg_basebackup/
```

Этот формат удобен тем что он практически готов к развертыванию в случае поломки. Просто распакуйте архив и запустите восстановление.

Дополнить архив рекомендую логом транзакций. В конфиге включил wal и добил строчку. Костыльно смотрится, можно обойтись `cp`, но экономлю место. В конфиге:

```
archive_command = 'test ! -f /backup/$(date +%F)/%f && mkdir -p /backup/$(date +%F)/ && cat %p | gzip > /backup/$(date +%F)/%f.gz'
```

Если есть предложения как улучшить это - буду рад. Но скорее перенесу функции сжатия на другой сервер. Тут оставлю просто `cp`.

Именя дамп - нужно сутки чтоб его развернуть на большой базе.
Имея один архив pg_basebackup можно развернуться за пару часов, а если потренироваться то и за полчаса.
Имея 2 перечисленных архива можно восстановить базу в состояние за 15 минут перед крахом, а не за сутки до него.

> Бэкап не считается бэкапом пока его не попробуете восстановить!

Comment: Большое спасибо за еще один способ. Но на данный момент разбираемся именно с Dump. База занимет примерно 5гб, а в архиве 1,2гб. Время на создание и востановление дампа ~1ч.30мин, это без доп. настроек. Именно к вашему методу мне добавить нечего, так как только второй день разбираюсь в этой теме.

Comment: Стоит обратить особое внимание, что для `pg_basebackup -x` необходимо либо пристально отслеживать хватило ли сохранённых WAL либо обязательно должен быть архив WAL. Чаще используется `-X stream` требующих 2 коннекта репликации, но самостоятельно копирующий WAL. К `archive_command` есть _большие_ нарекания - на текущую дату полагаться нельзя. К тому же как потом доставать wal из архива? Чтобы не собирать конструктор вручную - есть barman.

Comment: @Мелкий Дата нужна для того чтоб не было каталога на миллион файлов. 
Ещё удобно скопировать каталог на определенную дату: pg_basebackup плюс walы за день.

Восстановление обратно что-то вроде `find /backup/ -name %f.gz -exec gunzip -c > %p`
Попробую barman, спс